# writing tests in solidity for functions returning multiple values

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, truffle-contract

I have a function that returns multiple values

```
function getInfo(string id) returns(string x,string y){ bytes32 _id= strToBytes(id);
    return (infostruct[_id].x,infostruct[_id].y) ; }
```

Now i want to test this function using solidity test in truffle

```
function testBaseContract(){
 BaseContract basecontract= BaseContract(DeployedAddresses.BaseContract());

        var (x,y) = basecontract.getInfo("1");
        Assert.equal(x,"198/180","this id data is not accessible to you or doesn't exist at all.");
}
```

i don't know how to access multiple return values in solidity, this was my best guess and I am getting the error

```
TypeError: Member "equal" is not available in type(library Assert) outside of storage.
```

Comment: The problems appear to be with the function returning strings not with it being a tuple. It work when you use bytes32 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the result it gives you back is truffle, you can either use explode to compare the result with expected in terms or object/array. But you access the result like the following -

```
basecontract.getInfo("1",function(error,data){
            // data returns a tuple  
            var rowdata = data.toString().split(',')

            // you can access the values through array rowdata[0]
            // do the comparison

          })
```

Comment: this is how one can do in JavaScript, how do I do this in Solidity

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
var (x,y) = basecontract.getInfo("1");
```

To this:

```
var [x,y] = await basecontract.getInfo("1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this puts the return values in the response array.
var repsonse = await basecontract.getInfo("1");

Now you can read the items as array elements like response[0] and response[1].

It worked for me.